# Apply Physics2D to 3D Game Objects - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

Is it possible to use Physics 2D components(rigidbody2d,collider2d..etc) on 3d Game objects. I am planning develop 2 game with some of 3d model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not, however what you can do with rigidbody3d is lock the physics movement and rotation on it. For example, if you only ever wanted it to move along the x and y axis of your game, in the inspector just tick the freeze z movement box for the rigidbody component.